# Executing a script inside an unknown directory

Tags: shell-script, shell

I have a script, pleaseRunMe.sh. I'd like to execute said script from inside a larger shell script.

The script name will never change, however the directory it lives in **will** be different based on the build of a product I want to install:

Today:

```
/opt/foo/bar/baz/scripts.0621/pleaseRunMe.sh
```

Tomorrow:

```
/opt/foo/bar/baz/scripts.0622/pleaseRunMe.sh
```

I guess I could do something which involves using a recursive find against the /baz directory ala:

```
thepath = find /opt/foo/bar/baz -name "pleaseRuneMe.sh" 
use $thepath here
```

....but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way to address this. In my perfect, new-to-shell-scripting world, I'd want to simply execute /opt/foo/bar/baz/scripts.????/pleaseRunme.sh it it would magically work since there would be only one scripts.* directory under /baz.

Is there some magic you can show me?

Comment: Are you saying that `/opt/foo/bar/baz/scripts.????/pleaseRunMe.sh` doesn't work?

Comment: errrrr...I didn't even try it - assumed that it would be too good to be true. I just did, and it works like a charm. Please don't tell my cube-mate.

Comment: OK ;) However I'm not sure it's good programming practice.

Comment: You could just execute `$(find /opt/foo/bar/baz -type f -name "pleaseRunMe.sh")`.